# Enable HTML code only in Dreamweaver's Designer

Tags: dreamweaver

I need some HTML code to be processed only by Dreamweaver's Designer.
To be more exact, I need smth. like this:

```html
<html>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles_print.css" title="printer_friendly_css" />
  <!-- FOR_DREAMWEAVER_DESIGNER_ONLY
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css" title="normal_css" />
  -->
  ...
</html>
```

So that when this page is being viewed in Dreamweaver's Designer, the **effective** HTML looks like this (second tag is "uncommented"):

```html
<html>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles_print.css" title="printer_friendly_css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css" title="normal_css" />
  ...
</html>
```

and when the same page is being viewed somewhere else (e.g. in regular browser), it is processed as it should be (second tag is ignored because it is commented).

Is this possible? Does Dreamweaver have this kind of feature?

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver has a feature called Design Time Style sheets to handle this type of functionality. It allows you to apply styles only within Dreamweaver not on the live page. You can even hide styles at design time that would be present live.
Format -> CSS Styles -> Design-time

Adobe help for Design time style sheets:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7e17a.html

You can even use design time style sheets to help you track down potential problems with your CSS. Here's an article I wrote a while a go about that topic:
http://www.webassist.com/free-downloads/tutorials-and-training/roadmaps/roadmap_07.php

If you're using PHP and you want to apply site-wide and you have an include that is in every page take a look at:
http://james.revillini.com/2008/01/24/solved-dreamweaver-site-wide-design-time-style-sheets-using-templates/

Dreamweaver extension that can apply them site wide (Commercial, but only $5, haven't tried in in several versions of Dreamweaver, but I think it should still work):
http://www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=61265

Comment: thank you for your advice. Both my stylesheets (used in the sample HTML code in the first post) ARE NEEDED at run time. So it seems that I need to create **the 3rd** stylesheet - with same contents as "styles_print.css" - specially for design time usage, right?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to accomplish, but if you want to add a style sheet only for Dreamweaver design time, then you'll need to add the new style sheet via the Design time style sheets.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve my problem following your recommendations!